# Find all $a,b$ such that $\overline{a,b}=b/a$ where $(a,b)=1$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> We are given $a$ and $b$ such that $(a,b)=1$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$. If we write number $a$, then add a decimal point, and write number $b$ after it, we get a certain number $k$. If $k=b/a$, find all such $a$ and $b$.

My attempt was to notice that $\overline{a,b}=b/a$ actually means that $b=a^2+ab/10^m$, where $m$ is number of digits of $b$. I can solve this for $a$ or $b$. Is this good way of thinking at all?

Comment: Looks good. It means that $a$ and $b$ divide $10^m$, which at least cuts down the search.

Comment: Are you sure _both_ of them have to divide $10^m$?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Yes, but it's important to use $(a,b)=1$ to see this.  Try clearing denominators to get an integer equation, and reduce mod $a$ or $b$.

Comment: Can someone fully elaborate that statement? After that, I think it's fairy easy to argue that $2,5=5/2$ is the only solution, which was obvious from the start.

Comment: We have $10^mb=10^m a^2+ab$. Thus $a$ divides the right hand side, so it divides $10^mb$. But $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, so $a$ divides $10^m$. For $b$, note that $b$ divides two of the terms, so it divides the third, $10^ma^2$. But $b$ and $a^2$ are relatively prime, and we are finished.

Comment: And after that since $(a,b)=1$ it must be $m=1$ and $a=2,b=5$ is the only solution that satisfies, right?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović I don't see how it's quite so immediate.   Since $(a,b)=1$ we have $ab \mid 10^m$, but also $10^m \mid ab$ (since $b-a^2$ is an integer).  Thus $ab=10^m$, and it's pretty simple to narrow things from there.

Comment: @ErickWong So $m=1$ is pretty obvious. But (noting $ab=10^m$), for $m\geq 2$ $10^m$ can be factored as $2^m \cdot 5^m$, and since they're coprime, it yields that $a=2^m$ and $b=5^m$ (or other way around, but it's obvious that $b>a$; also it's obvious none of them is $1$). So what now? How to prove that $m\geq 2$ won't work?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Now just don't panic, and use your original equation (alternatively use the fact that $b$ has $m$ digits, but that requires checking $m \le 3$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments above one is already led to $ab=10^m$, so we have now:
$b=a²+1$. Since $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, and $ab=10^m$, either $a=1, b=10^m$, or $a=2^m, b=5^m$. The former is just impossible, and the latter implies $5^m=2^{2m}+1$. So  $2^{2m}+1 \equiv 0 \pmod5$, viz. $m$ must be odd. Now, if $m$ is $>1$, then $5^m-1\equiv 0 \pmod8$, viz. $m$ must be even. This contradiction shows that $m=1$ and $a=2, b=5$.

Answer (score 1):

Observe $\overline{0,b} = b/10^m$. From this your identity follows by multiplying by $a$ on both sides.

IOW: Your approach is correct.

Comment: I am not so sure if the definition of OP for the natural integers includes $0$. Also I am uncertain about how to obtain the solutions of the problem from this point on wards. Thanks for the explanation in advance.

Comment: Whether $0 \in \Bbb N$ is irrelevant. It's simply an algebraic identity that $\overline{a,b} = a + \overline{0,b}$.

Comment: Yes, but I cannot see its relation with the multiplication by $a$.

Comment: But if $a=0$, then the condition $(a,b)=1$ implies that $b=1$.

Comment: The OPs relation $b = a^2 + ab/10^m$ follows by multiplying by $a$. There is nothing suggesting $a = 0$. Please read more carefully.

Comment: Sorry. I misread your answer. This reduction is indeed nice. Thanks for the explanations.